# radio button not showing the state checked in backbone code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to maintain the checked state in the browser for the radio button...
but i dont see the checked state in the browser...
i am using backbone marionette code..
is it a bug when i use it in my backbone view js..
since when i use it as normal html i dont see that bug in fiidle..
providing my code below...

**templates**

```
<ul class="bullet-list Soccer-options">
    <li><input type="radio" name="new-Soccer" value="Use new Soccer ">Use new Soccer</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="existing-Soccer" value="Use existing Soccer">Use existing Soccer</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="no-Soccer" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>

**views**

 ui: {
            arrow: '.sports-carrousel__form-border-arrow',
            soccerOptions: 'input[name=soccer]'
        },

        events: {
            'click .sports-carrousel__form-close': 'closeForm',
            'change @ui.soccerOptions': 'togglesoccerOptions'
        },

toggleSoccerOptions: function(e) {
    var inputName = $(e.currentTarget).prop('name');
    debugger;

    switch(inputName) {
        case 'new-Soccer':
            this.isNewSoccer = true;
            this.isExistingSoccer = this.isNoSoccer = false;
            break;
        case 'existing-Soccer':
            this.isExistingSoccer = true;
            this.isNewSoccer = this.isNoSoccer = false;
            break;
        case 'no-Soccer':
            this.isNoSoccer = true;
            this.isExistingSoccer = this.isNewSoccer = false;
            break;
    }

    this.render();
},
```

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks for your reply..i posted only related code...updating my code...

Comment: I'm guessing that there is some Marionette stuff involved but I don't know any Marionette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spelling your event handler name two different ways.

`'togglesoccerOptions'` and `toggleSoccerOptions`

Notice the capital `S`.

If the call isn't happening at all, then this is a likely candidate.